# how do i sort my highscore list with name from a file?-java

Tags: java, sorting, scoring

I am trying to sort my highscores for my snake game in java:  I want to be able to sort them from a file.

an example of the file would be:

1. George : 200
2. Sarah : 700
3. Ben : 100
4. Fred : 400
5. AJ : 300

How could i sort the name and all to be:

1. Sarah : 700
2. Fred : 400
3. AJ : 300
4. George : 200
5. Ben : 100

If you could explain how to do it, send some code if you have done it before or send me to a link that explains it well, that would be Great!! thanks

Comment: Scan the file, insert each string from the file (delimited by a new line) into an ArrayList<String> and then use regex to grab the number at the end of the line. Sort the ArrayList according to the numbers at the end of each string and then write the sorted ArrayList to the file.

Answer (score 0):

You need a max-heap for this

1. Read all the values from the file row by row. While reading use the split function to split by : . That will give you a name followed by score. Create an object where id is score and value is an object containing score and name. ( You do need to factor in equal scores).

   String[] values = input.split(":);
   String name =values[0];
   String score =values[1];
2. Create a max heap and insert the elements one by one into the heap. 
   --In java you can use the PriorityQueue Object for this data structure
3. After they are done keep popping out elements one by one . This will give you all the elements in a descending order. Since your object contains both score and name you can use it to print the results in a descending order

Use the "poll" methods of the PriorityQueue to achieve this

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

Answer (score -1):

As my comment described:

Read the input file line by line, store the values matched by a regex expression into a TreeMap (a sorted HashMap, which is reverse sorted in this case), then write these values back to the file in the correct order.

Input: "scores.txt":

```
1.  George : 200
2.  Sarah : 700
3.  Ben : 100
4.  Fred : 400
5.  AJ : 300
```

Output:

```
1.  Sarah : 700
2.  Fred : 400
3.  AJ : 300
4.  George : 200
5.  Ben : 100
```

---

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.io.*;

public class regex {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws java.io.IOException {       
        File file = new File("scores.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);

        //create a TreeMap in reverse order otherwise it will sort ascending instead of descending
        Map<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<Integer, String>(Collections.reverseOrder());

        String regexp = "\\d*\\.\\s*([a-zA-Z]*)\\s*\\:\\s*(\\d*)";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexp);

        while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
            Matcher match = pattern.matcher(scan.nextLine());
            while (match.find()) {  
                //insert into the map the score : name --->  (\\d*) : ([a-zA-Z]*)
                map.put(Integer.parseInt(match.group(2)), match.group(1));
            }
        }

        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));

        int count = 1;
        for (Map.Entry entry : map.entrySet()) {
            //writes ->       1. George : 100 \n
            bw.write(count + ".  " + entry.getValue() + " : " + entry.getKey() + "\n");
            count++;
        }   

        bw.close();
    }
}
```